# How to go to another line in bat? (writing)

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I want to make a .bat file to write a .vbs file but to go to 2 lines:

```
@echo off
 echo.>"E:\Desktop\lol\somewhat.vbs"
@echo X=MsgBox("Yes HELLO GOOD DAY! PRESS 1") if X=1 then MsgBox "OMG YOU PRESSED",64,"LOL"> somewhat.vbs
```

I want `if X=1 then MsgBox "OMG YOU PRESSED",64,"LOL"` to be the second line.

Comment: I think `End If` is missing in your pice of code.

Comment: @reporter You don't need an `End If` if the statement is a one liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it something like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
>"E:\Desktop\lol\somewhat.vbs" (
    Echo X=MsgBox("Yes HELLO GOOD DAY! PRESS 1"^)
    Echo If X=1 Then MsgBox "OMG YOU PRESSED",64,"LOL"
)
```

*Note the caret, **`^`**, which is used to escape the closing parenthesis in your VBS code in order to prevent it closing the block early*.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!